# What's the difference between a "control" and an "element"?

Tags: web-development, terminology

In web development, you often hear the terms "[element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element)" and "control". The term "element" is often associated with HTML, and you hear the term "control" most often in Asp.NET development... but the w3c refers to controls in the [Forms in HTML documents recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2), blurring the lines a little.

What is a control and what is an element? How are they the same and how are they different? Is one a generalization of the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Element refers to [DOM Elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html). In other words, every part of the page is an element. Javascript/DHTML is all about manipulating these elements to make the page interactive.

A control, in the W3C sense, is a type of element that accepts user input. Things like textboxes, radio buttons, and submit buttons are all controls under this definition.

The ASP.Net definition of a control is different from the W3C version. In ASP.Net, a control is a template that takes data and formats it as HTML. So, for example, a `GridView` control takes the data that you give it and formats it as a `<table>`. A `Label` formats data as a `<span>`. ASP.Net controls allow you to work at a higher level of abstraction than the W3C DOM. You can work with `Labels`, `GridViews` and `Repeaters`, rather than having to work out the HTML generation yourself.

Comment: That would of been my answer too!